# При переходе на страницу записи разворачиваются записи в сайдбаре

Tags: php, wordpress

Фишка в том, что посты выводятся циклом в сайдбаре, длинна записи ограничивается readmore тегом. Но при переходе на страницу записи, записи в сайдбаре тоже "разворачиваются".

Код в сайдбаре:

```
<?php       
query_posts(array(
'post__not_in' => array( get_the_ID() ),
'showposts' => 3,
'post_type' => 'special-guest'
));
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
?>      
<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<blockquote>
    <?php
    $my_excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
    if ( $my_excerpt != '' ){
        echo "<p><small>". $my_excerpt ."</small></p>";
    }
    ?>
</blockquote>                   
<div class="thumb">
<?php 
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
    the_post_thumbnail();
} 
?>
</div>
<?php       
echo content(80);
?>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<?php endwhile;?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Код в index.php:

```
<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <?php the_date('d-m-Y', '<abbr>', '</abbr>'); ?>
    <div class="thumb">
        <?php 
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
            the_post_thumbnail();
        } 
        ?>
    </div>      
    <?php the_content(); ?> 
    <div class="clearfix"></div>        
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
```

Простите, но здесь нет того, что вы ищите...

```
<?php endif; ?>
```

Поиск и чтение кодекса дали только знание того, что для вторичных loop нужно использовать `get_posts`, но это тоже разворачивает `readmore`.
Есть идеи?

Comment: Проблема решилась указанием глобальной переменной для the_content();
<?php 
  global $more;    // Объявим переменную $more как глобальную (перед Циклом WordPress).
  $more = 0;       // Изменим значение переменной, чтобы показать только текст до тега more.
  the_content();
  ?>

Comment: Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.